# How to handle image uploads with jquery post submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, image-upload, jqueryform

I have the html form and i am submittng the form with jquery with following

```
var queryString = $('.form1').formSerialize(); 
 $.post('book/create/', queryString);
```

But if i submit form without ajax then image gets uploaded by django function

Now the problem is , it is ignoring the file fields. what should i do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot upload files using XMLHttpRequest (AJAX).But you can try using some of the Ajax JQuery plugins to upload files

- http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/
- http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html

Also Check [how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)